# Getting data from .net mapping table

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, database

I have an ASP.net MVC app that has an AngularJS front end.
I have the following setup in my database.

[image]

I generated the models from my database, but the cms_user_group table doesn't get generated as a model.
I need to get a list of cms_groups that a user belongs to, and I also need to add/remove users from those groups. How to I access the cms_user_group information?